# Error 404 domain/.well-known/apple-app-site-association

Tags: ios, http-status-code-404, ios-universal-links, apple-app-site-associate, apple-app-site-association

I am getting a 404 error when loading my apple-app-site-association and I have no idea why... Here's how my file looks like:

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appIDs": [ "ABCDE12345.com.example.app" ],
        "components": [
          {
            "/": "*",
            "comment": "Matches any URL"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "appID": "ABCDE12345.com.example.app",
        "paths": [ "*" ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The file is located under root `/.well-known/apple-app-site-association`. If I try to access to it through route, I'm always getting a 404 error.

[image]

Does anyone know why? I'd say I'm missing some web configuration, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that I was missing the type for the files without any extension.

```
  <mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="application/json" />
```

Ref.: https://medium.com/@barsh/my-first-date-with-ios-universal-links-90dfabc88bb8